# How to trigger Jquery event on form action after page loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a checkbox which is preselected checkbox and after clicking it. jQuery function is called and display the form action.

```
<form id="lcform" action="${requestContextPath }/checkout/applyLPDisc.mobi" method="get">
    <input type="checkbox" id="lch" name="lch" value="Loyal" checked>Loyalty Discount<br>
</form>
```

I have requirement to load form action on the basis of pre-selected checkbox  and the jQuery event is triggered once the page loads i.e. no need to click the checkbox.

I have requirement to load form action on the basis of pre-selected checkbox  and the Jquery event is triggered once the page loads i.e. no need to click the checkbox.
    jQuery function :

```
$('#lch').bind('click', function() {
    if(this.checked == true){
        document.getElementById('lcform').submit();
    }
});
```

I have requirement to load form action on the basis of pre-selected checkbox  and the Jquery event is triggered once the page loads i.e. no need to click the checkbox.

Comment: I wonder if this is really the approach you want to load a page and direct submit it as a form since you should know already if the checkbox will be set or not? But I guess http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/ is what you want

Answer (score 1):

You can try this for example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($('#lch').is(":checked") == true){
        document.getElementById('lcform').submit();
    }
});
```

Tell me if it works!

Answer (score 1):

Can be done simply as follows,

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  ($('#lch').is(":checked"))? document.getElementById('lcform').submit() : false;   

});
```

Comment: Please do not change the code in questions and answers, as it can change the intention of the poster. Once you have enough rep, you will be able to comment, and you can suggest changes to the poster that way. Thank you.